# Is the smooth singular simplicial set of a smooth manifold a Kan complex?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, differential-topology, simplicial-complexes

It is classical that the singular simplicial set of a topological space is a Kan complex. This is elementary and already due to presumably Kan.

Q: Is the smooth singular simplicial set of a smooth manifold a Kan complex?

More specifically, given a smooth manifold $Y$ we have the simplicial set $Y_{\bullet}$ whose set of $k$-simplices is the set of smooth maps $\Delta^k \to Y$, (a smooth map of a manifold with corners). Is $Y_{\bullet}$ a Kan complex?

Comment: Thinking about this more carefully, I think the answer is just no. Consider the horn of a 3-simplex mapping to $R^3$. For the map to smoothly extend,  there are three constraints for the differential at the vertex point coming from face differentials. We could accommodate 2 constraints but generically could not accommodate all three.

Comment: These constraints are not independent.

Comment: You are absolutely right, in fact the third constraint is determined by the other 2. This is actually enough to convince me that the answer is yes, heuristically.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, see Corollary 4.36 in Christensen–Wu [The homotopy theory of diffeological spaces](https://arxiv.org/abs/1311.6394).

Comment: As far as I remember they have collared simplices, in which case the answer is pretty trivially yes.

Comment: @Yasha: The proofs of 4.36 and its dependencies 4.36, 4.34, 4.30, and 4.28 work equally well for compact simplices.